# Alterar tipo de coluna de Banco de Dados PostegreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Preciso mudar o tipo de coluna de uma tabela

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
ALTER TABLE cadastro_remetente ALTER COLUMN ssl_smtp DROP DEFAULT;

ALTER TABLE cadastro_remetente ALTER COLUMN ssl_smtp SET DEFAULT FALSE;

ALTER TABLE cadastro_remetente ALTER ssl_smtp TYPE bool USING CASE WHEN ssl_smtp='TRUE' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END;'
```

smtp  atualmente é character varying

está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> ERRO:  restrição de verificação "ssl_smtp" foi violada por algum registro
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERRO: restrição de verificação "ssl_smtp" foi violada por algum registro
> SQL state: 23514

Todos os registro estão como TRUE ou FALSE

alguem pode me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Se a coluna é boolean, os valores aceitos são, `t`/`f`, `true`/`false`, `1`/`0`. Não entendi o `ssl_smtp DROP DEFAULT` nem o CASE. Você quer altera o tipo da coluna e manter os valores?

Comment: Veja pelo pgAdmin se nessa tabela tem alguma coluna com uma constraint/restrição.

Comment: CONSTRAINT pk_cadastro_remetente PRIMARY KEY (id). atualmente a tabela ssl_smtp é character varying e eu quero alterar para boolean, e isso é que não estou conseguindo.....

Comment: Talvez tenha algum `check` ou domain na coluna `ssl_smtp` de uma verificada.

Comment: Mostre a estrutura da tabela com `\d cadastro_remetente` no psql

Comment: eu procurei na internet e pelo que eu li será necessario criar uma nova tabela... passar as informacoes para la, excluir a antiga tabela e depois renomear a nova tabela...

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE cadastro_remetente
  ADD COLUMN "ssl_smtp" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Comment: Essa informação é se eu fosse criar... eu não quero criar, eu quero ALTERAR de character varying para boolean. nessa coluna existe duas informações ou vai ser FALSE ou vai ser TRUE e eu quero transformar isso em boolean

Answer (score 0):

meio antiga mas acredito que sirva para consultas futuras.

se a coluna tiver dados, e eles não ferirem as regras do novo tipo, algo assim deve resolver.

```
alter table cadastro_remetente alter column ssl_smtp  type boolean
```